# List of all connected IP's to server SSH

Tags: ssh, connection

How can I get a list of all connected IP-adresses that do have a connection to the server using SSH?

I want to get a list of all IP addresses that do have a connection, including bots.

Answer (score 3):

> sudo netstat -tanp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep ssh | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/:.*//'

- netstat for listing all connections with ports and daemons
- filter only ESTABLISHED connections
- filter only SSH connections
- print only remote IP address
- remove port part